# Error while calling a function from one module to another module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

i have written two modules in python "Sample.py" and "GenericFunctions.py" from "Sample.py", iam calling a function

present in "GenericFunctions.py" but i am not able to call that function getting error as "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'fn_ElseLog'"

### Code in Sample.py:

```
import GenericFunctions

def sampleee():
    g_TCaseID="SD1233"
    g_TCDescription="Login"
    g_TestData="hi"
    g_Result="Fail"

    g_Remarks="testing"
    g_TargetEnvironment="S1"
    g_TargetSystem="Legacy"
    g_TargetRegion="EU"
    x = GenericFunctions.fn_ElseLog(g_TCaseID, g_TCDescription, g_TestData, g_Result, g_Remarks)


sampleee()
```

### Code in GenericFunctions.py:

```
def fn_ElseLog(g_TCaseID, g_TCDescription, g_TestData, g_Result, g_Remarks):

    print "entered in ElseLog Function"
    Output= fn_Output(g_TCaseID, g_TCDescription, g_TestData, g_Result , g_Remarks)
    print ("Testcase"+"'"+g_TCDescription+"'"+"execution completed"+"'"+g_TargetEnvironment+"-"+g_TargetRegion)

def fn_Output(p_TCaseID, p_TCDescription, p_TestData, p_Result , p_Remarks):
    OutputSheet=""
    OutputSheet="\Test"+"_"+g_TargetEnvironment+"_"+g_TargetSystem+"_"+g_TargetRegion+".xlsx" 
    OutputPath=r"C:\Users\u304080\Desktop\PlayAround\Shakedowns\OutputResultFiles"

    #objExcel1 = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    Outputfile=os.path.exists(OutputPath+OutputSheet)

    if Outputfile==True :
       print('Output file is present')
    else:
       print('Output file is not present')
       return

    objExceloutput = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
     #excel.DisplayAlerts = False
    objoutputworkbook = objExceloutput.Workbooks.Open(OutputPath+OutputSheet)
    objSheetOutput = objoutputworkbook.Sheets(1)
    OutputRowCount =objSheetOutput.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    print "OutputRowcount" , OutputRowCount
    objSheetOutput.Cells(OutputRowCount+1,1).Value=p_TCaseID
    objSheetOutput.Cells(OutputRowCount+1,2).Value=p_TCDescription
    objSheetOutput.Cells(OutputRowCount+1,3).Value=p_TestData
    objSheetOutput.Cells(OutputRowCount+1,4).Value=p_Result
    objSheetOutput.Cells(OutputRowCount+1,4).Font.Bold = True

    if p_Result=="Pass":
       objSheetOutput.Cells(OutputRowCount+1,1).Font.ColorIndex = 10 
    else:
       objSheetOutput.Cells(OutputRowCount+1,1).Font.ColorIndex = 3

    objoutputworkbook.SaveAs(OutputPath)
    objSheetOutput=None
    objoutputworkbook=None
    objExceloutput.Quit()
    objExceloutput=None
```

Can you guys show me a solution for this?

Comment: are they in the same directory?

Comment: @samrap how to know that they are in the same directory or not !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. delete all `pyc` files in your directory. (to ensure it is not in cached)
2. `print(dir(GenericFunctions))` and `print(GenericFunctions.__file__)` in `Sample.py`, to see if you are importing the file you think you are importing.
3. see if there are other files called `GenericFunctions` somewhere on your `PYTHONPATH` (echo $PYTHONPATH).

Comment: @RickeyA  as u suggested i tried with  print(GenericFunctions.__file__) in the output it is printing two files with the same name as "C:\workspace\sample\GenericFunctions.pyc
C:\workspace\sample\GenericFunctions.pyc" then what i have to do now

Comment: there are two files in my workspace one is compiled python file and python file ...is it correct to have two files like that ??

Comment: @somesh: Yes, the .py holds your code, and when you run that a .pyc file is created by the interpreter that holds the intermediate bytecode. You can delete the .pyc file to see if that solves your problem.

Comment: @somesh: it is strange the filename is printed twice. Are you including sample.py in another module?

Comment: yes...i included in GenericFunctions.py ..is it correct or not ??

Comment: That would be the problem. You create a import to the same module. You should not do that. In GenericFunctions.py you should not import GenericFunctions again.

Comment: In GenericFunctions.py i included sample.py and in sample.py i included GenericFunctions.py is this wrong ??

Comment: Yes, that is a circular dependency. Do not import sample in GenericFunctions.py.

Answer (score 1):

> present in "GenericFunctions.py" but i am not able to call that
>   function getting error as "AttributeError: 'module' object has 
>   no attribute 'fn_ElseLog'"

As presented, your code looks correct.

Check to make sure both files are in the same directory, then either restart your python or do a `reload(GenericFunctions)` to make sure you don't have an out-of-date version in the `sys.modules` cache.